# how i use two spinner in the same page

Tags: java, android, html, xcode, spinner

```
public class service extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service);


        Spinner spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1); // Spinner code
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this,
                R.array.serviceD,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    }
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(this, adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
```

How can add another spinner in same page?

Answer (score 0):

In `onNothingSelected` and `onItemSelected` method you can check id like below -

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        int id = adapterView.getId();
        switch (id)
        {
            case R.id.spinner1:
                Log.d("Selected_Value","Spinner 1 : "+adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                break;
            case R.id.spinner2:
                 Log.d("Selected_Value","Spinner 2 : "+adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try one with this.

```
 String[] weeks = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "thursday"};
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMethodInterviews);
    Spinner spinnerSecond = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMethodSecond);
    ArrayAdapter<String>   spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            R.layout.custom_title, android.R.id.text1, weeks);

    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.cutom_spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinnerSecond.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerSecond.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


  and when on click of item check id and get items

          @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    int id = adapterView.getId();
    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.spinnerMethodInterviews:
            Log.e("spinnerFirst",adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerMethodSecond:
            Log.e("spinnerSecond",adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

Comment: In your code set spinner 1 click listener and adapter

Comment: let me know if you face any issue